# Real Analysis - Assessing the number of zeros

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, polynomials, roots

I am struggling with answering this question for my Real Analysis course.

"Prove, by induction on *n*, that is *p* is a polynomial of degree *n*, then the function

*e^x - p(x)*

has at most *n+1* zeros. (Start with the case *n* = 0.) "

Comment: What about induction on the degree $n$ ? Also if $f(x)=e^x-p(x)$ has $n+1$ zeros, then $f'(x)$ has $n$ zeroes.

Comment: Ask yourself what role Rolle might play.